# When is the right time to call robot.cleanUp()

Tags: java, unit-testing, swing, junit, fest

I'm using JUnit and FEST for Swing integration testing of our app that I start and stop, multiple times in the test case. **Should `@after` include a call to `robot.cleanUp()`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is as follows: each initialization site of a FrameFixture should have a corresponding cleanup site.

Sepcifically, if your `@Before` method initializes a FrameFixture (as in: `w = new FrameFixture<MyWindow>()` where w is a field of the test class) then you should define a `@After` method that will release the resources via `w.cleanUp()`.

See the sample in: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Getting+Started.